# OSX Controlling the keyboard with Python: hold duration

Tags: python, macos, keypress

I'm trying to get Python 3.5 to control the keyboard on OS X, using some code I found using Quartz Event Taps.

```
def KeyPress(k):
    keyCode, shiftKey = toKeyCode(k)
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None, keyCode,True))
    time.sleep(3.0001)
    CGEventPost(kCGSessionEventTap, CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(None,keyCode,False))
```

So you would think increasing the x in time.sleep(x) should increase how long the key is held down for, but it does not seem to be working. I have another bit of code that will wait 4 seconds for me to activate another application, like Terminal or TextEdit, and then calls KeyPress('s') to hold down the s key. It prints the s and pauses, but if I actually hold the key down, it would continue to print sssss. So it does not seem to be actually holding the key down, as I would like.

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out? I'm having the same problem

Comment: Sadly no, I moved on to other projects.